# Error in fix_replacement(replacement) in R

Tags: r, lubridate

Say , i have the dates

```
trainingData$Date=30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
30-01-2015,
```

I need transform it to create the new variable

```
trainingData$WeekOfYear <- as.numeric(stringr::str_replace(trainingData$Date, "%W"))
```

but then got the error

```
Error in fix_replacement(replacement) : 
  argument "replacement" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the function `week()` from `lubridate`, it seems that you need only the week number of the year, right?

```
week(as.Date("2018-12-01"))
week(as.Date(trainingData$Date))
```

> Error in fix_replacement(replacement) : 
>     argument "replacement" is missing, with no default

The function you call needs a replacement to be specified. See the `help(str_replace)`:

```
str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)
```

You just gave the pattern.